# Run desktop exe from asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a desktop exe file like (notopad.exe) in a specific directorynow i want to run my exe from my asp.net MVC3 web application. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You may want to enhance the question as it can be read two ways: I want to run an application on the server for some purpose OR I want to run an application on the server and interact with the UI over my web session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Process.Start("notepad.exe")` from the [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class.